# Adding record using C# windows form and msaccess

Tags: c#, ms-access

i created a msaccess database(MyWorkers.mdb) it contains one table(tblWorkers)

Code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Insertfrm1 : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection conn;
        public OleDbDataAdapter da;
        public DataSet ds;
        public DataTable dt;
        public OleDbCommand cmd;
        public OleDbDataReader dr;
        public int maxrecords;
        public int pointer;
        static public int cnt;
        public string wid;

        public Insertfrm1()
        {
            cnt++;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Insertfrm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\MyWorkers1.mdb");
            conn.Open();
            pointer = 0;
            filldata();
            navigation();

        }
        public void filldata()
        {
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblWorkers", conn);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            maxrecords = dt.Rows.Count;
        }
        public void navigation()
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no Data available");
            }
            else
            {
                txtworkersid.Text = dt.Rows[pointer].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                txtname.Text = dt.Rows[pointer].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                txtjobtitle.Text = dt.Rows[pointer].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            }
        }

        public void clrdata()
        {
            txtworkersid.Clear();
            txtname.Clear();
            txtjobtitle.Clear();
            txtworkersid.Focus();
        }

        private void btnclear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtworkersid.Clear();
            txtname.Clear();
            txtjobtitle.Clear();
            txtworkersid.Focus();
        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Boolean inc = false;
            if (txtworkersid.Text == "")
            {
                DialogResult sav = MessageBox.Show("The Worker ID is Empty", "Blank Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtname.Text == "")
            {
                DialogResult sav = MessageBox.Show("The Workers Name is Empty", "Blank Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtjobtitle.Text == "")
            {
                DialogResult sav = MessageBox.Show("The Job Title is Empty", "Balnk record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                //string cmdstr = "SELECT Workers_ID FROM tblWorkers WHERE (Workers_ID='" + txtworkersid.Text + "')";
                //cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, conn);
                cmd=new OleDbCommand("SELECT Workers_ID FROM tblWorkers WHERE (Workers_ID='" + txtname.Text + "')",conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (txtworkersid.Text == dr.GetValue(0).ToString())
                    {
                        DialogResult sav = MessageBox.Show("The Record is Duplicate", "Duplicate Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        inc = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr.NextResult();
                    }
                }
                if (inc == false)
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO tblWorkers(Workers_ID,name,job_title) VALUES ('" + txtworkersid.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtjobtitle.Text + "')";
                    Execute(sql);
                    DialogResult save = MessageBox.Show("Workers Record is saved Sucessfully.");
                    clrdata();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Execute(string sql)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            filldata();
        }

        private void txtworkersid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                DialogResult num = MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers are allowed", "invalid Key");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When i run this, it shows error like: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() statement
pls help me

thanks

**Edit:** complete code posted

Comment: @user: i have copied through the code which you posted as a suggested edit on two different answers in a different thread - please check and verify this edit. The other question looks like it contains code from the same app, if that is your account you may want to get them merged.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the value you are passing for `Workers_ID` to be compared against. First you pass through `txtname.Text`, then later on you try to insert `txtworkersid.Text` into that column.

Which should it be? And should you be leaving it as a string, or converting it to a number (and not enclosing it in quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Workers_ID column is numeric your SQL statements should be:

```
"SELECT Workers_ID FROM tblWorkers WHERE (Workers_ID=" + txtname.Text + ")"
```

and

```
"INSERT INTO tblWorkers(Workers_ID,name,job_title) VALUES (" + txtworkersid.Text + ",'" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtjobtitle.Text + "')"
```

Note the removal of the `'` quotes around the ID values.

Answer (score -1):

```
 cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Workers_ID FROM tblWorkers WHERE 
       (Workers_ID='" + txtname.Text + "')",conn);                 
//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

remove this as nonquery is for add,update, delete not querying.

and if *workerId* column type in *Db* is `int`, use remove single quote `'` from both sides.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Converting to Int32 won't help.  The SQL statement is a string, so a string value is okay, but you need to remove the `'` quotes from around it.